# not sure how to call my function from a new scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Hope this title is correct :)

I use the modular pattern:

```
(function (vvv, $, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    vvv = (function () {
        vvv.functionName = (function () {
            ...
        });
   ......
}(
    window.vvv = window.vvv || {},
    jQuery
));
```

I also use a debounce function made by [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

```
vvv.debounce = (function(func, wait, immediate) {
            var timeout;
            return function() {
                var context = this, args = arguments;
                var later = function() {
                    timeout = null;
                    if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
                };
                var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
                if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
            };
        });
```

I use the debounce function to call other functions on a certain window size. But now in those functions my main vvv object does not exist. Now to quickfix this, I simply call window.vvv.myfunction(). The fix is fine, but well, the point is that I want all my functions within the vvv object. Not sure why, this is more out of curiosity :) How would you fix this?

Comment: do not do `vvv =` inside your function

Comment: @Grundy hmm, what would you suggest otherwise and why?

Comment: just try this code :-) `(function (a){ a = 10})(window.b = {}); console.log(b);`

Comment: @Grundy b = {} Which I get, but I think you missed something to link them? :)

Comment: this code is a simplified version of your code: `window.b` passed as parameter to funciton, parameter `a` reference to `window.b` but inside function, you change reference, so any changes with `a` parameter would not be applied to `window.b`

Answer (score 0):

Manually bind your object to the new function. I guess you want to do something like this:

```
vvv.debounce(function() { /* do stuff */ }.bind(vvv), 100);
```

But check the browser compability of `.bind()`, not all IE versions support this. You could also use `jQuery.proxy`:

```
vvv.debounce($.proxy(function() { /* do stuff */ }, vvv), 100);
```

This should also work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep debounce inside vv and still make the callbacks resolve vv you can

```
return function() {
                var context = this, args = arguments;
                 context.vv = vv; // add prop vv to context which is "this"
                 ......
                 .....
}
```

IN your callbacks , you can access vv as `this.vv` instead of `window.vv`